# PyQt: Accesing Main Window's Data from a dialog?

Tags: python, pyqt, qdialog, qmainwindow

So, I'm using Python and PyQt. I have a Main Window that contains a QTableWidget, and a dialog that opens modally and has some QLineEdit widgets... All right so far, but I have 2 problems:

1. When the dialog opens, my Main Window freezes, and I don't really like that...
2. What I want, when I finish editing a QLineEdit, is that the program will search the QTableWidget, and if the text from the QLineEdit exists in the table, a dialog will come up and informe about that. That's the general idea. But, so far, I seem to only be able to create a new QTableWidget instance, and I can't use the data from the existing...

What can I do about these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wrote:

> and a dialog that opens modally

and then:

> When the dialog opens, my Main Window freezes

The docs [say](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdialog.html#exec):

> `int QDialog::exec () [slot]`
>
> Shows the dialog as a modal dialog,
>   blocking until the user closes it. The function returns a `DialogCode`
>   result. If the dialog is application modal, users cannot interact with
>   any other window in the same application until they close the dialog.
>
> If the dialog is window modal, only interaction with the parent window
>   is blocked while the dialog is open. By default, the dialog is
>   application modal.

About [modeless dialogs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdialog.html#modeless-dialogs):

> A modeless dialog is a dialog that operates independently of other
>   windows in the same application. Find and replace dialogs in
>   word-processors are often modeless to allow the user to interact with
>   both the application's main window and with the dialog.
>
> Modeless
>   dialogs are displayed using `show()`, which returns control to the
>   caller immediately.

An example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class SearchDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Search')
        self.searchEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.searchEdit)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class MainWindow(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, None)
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(320, 240))
        self.setWindowTitle('Main window')
        self.logText = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit()
        searchButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Search')
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.logText)
        layout.addWidget(searchButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        searchButton.clicked.connect(self.showSearchDialog)

    def showSearchDialog(self):
        searchDialog = SearchDialog(self)
        searchDialog.show()
        searchDialog.searchEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.onSearch)

    def onSearch(self):
        self.logText.appendPlainText(self.sender().text())



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Click 'Search' to open a search window (you can open several of them). Enter a text to search and press Enter. The text to search will be added to the log in the main window.

Comment: How can I get data from a modeless dialog after it is accepted?

Comment: `QDialog` has [`accepted`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#accepted) signal. Connect to it.

Comment: Yes, but, because the MainWindow and the QDialog belong to different classes, the data get mixed up...

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your problem.

Comment: Could you, please write a small, self contained example... I want to see how you would do it... To see what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: When I implement that in my own code I  get attribute errors: AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'lineEdit'

Comment: I tested it. If you put this code into a separate file - it works. In my code there is no a `lineEdit` attribute. Study the traceback to see why there is a problem

Comment: I didn't mean your code(which works fine) but my code when I tried to do it how you did it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15252/discussion-between-warwaruk-and-antoni4040)